# Why Youtrack is not closing an issue by commit message?

Tags: git, youtrack

I have installed Youtrack standalone to my PC. And added Gitlab project to it. I created an issue for testing with id #BDX-1 in Youtrack.

When I pushed commit with message **"Youtrack test commit #BDX-1 Fixed"** Youtrack didn't closed an issue automatically. Then I just attached gitlab commit in the VCS Changes section manually. This also didn't worked.

Then I installed Upsource too, and wanted to connect it to the Youtrack. This try was also failed. I tried to install an external Hub and connect both Upsource and Youtrack to it. Upsource failed with error HTTP 403 and Youtrack could not be migrated because of:

> Hub provides single sign-on and shared user management in JetBrains
>   web-based products.YouTrack always uses Hub for authentication,
>   authorization, and user management, even when installed alone.
>
> If Hub integration is disabled, the following features are not
>   available: LDAP/OAuth/Google authentication, CAPTCHA, and the most
>   part of user registration settings.
>
> The following deployment models are supported:
>
> — Preconfigured Hub instance embedded in YouTrack distribution that works right away after installation. You can use this page to
>   adjust connection parameters, if necessary.
>   — External Hub instance that may be used by YouTrack to share user data with other JetBrains applications. **Current installation does not
>   support external Hub integration.**

The version of Youtrack I have installed seems doesn't support Hub Integration, but anyway Youtrack should close an issue when VCS commits added manually, right?

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I pushed commit with message "Youtrack test commit #BDX-1 Fixed" Youtrack is not closing an issue automatically.

The correct command term may differ if the State field has [state machine script](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Workflow-Rules.html) attached. One can check the same command to be applicable from a command window. If it works from a command window, then it should also work from a commit message.

> The version of Youtrack I have installed seems doesn't support Hub Integration

You must be using JAR distribution package. Only ZIP and MSI distributions can be used with a standalone Hub instance.

Comment: #BDX-1 Fixed should also work. Refer to the link [Executing Commands from a Comment to a VCS Change Commit](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD4/Executing+Commands+from+Comment+to+VCS+Commit)

Comment: Well, it really depends on your YouTrack server configuration. The documentation is a bit incomplete on that matter. See updated answer for details.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I need to have a look at server configuration indeed.

Comment: In my case I have to use something like `#EX-1 Status Completed` as I don't have a 'fixed' option and I changed the default `state` field to `status`